# Jquery/Datatable: want to display the last page at load but page() and fnPageChange doesn't works

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to display the last page of my Datatable when page is loaded.

But as mentionned in title, I try the 2 solutions I've read on forums and in documentation but it doesn't work for me.
I use the basic of Datatable...

```
$(document).ready( function () {

        // http://live.datatables.net/ficemafo/1/edit
        $("#table_id").one("preInit.dt", function () {
                $("#table_id_filter label").append('<a data-target="" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'randomization_settings:edit' %}" style="width: 190px;margin-left:10px;">Modify settings</a>');

        });        

        if(window.navigator.language.slice(0, 2) == 'fr'){
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5,10],
                "pageLength": 4,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                },
            });
            table.page('last').draw(false);
        } else {
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5,10],
                "pageLength": 4,
                "bAutoWidth": false, 
            });
            table.page('last').draw(false);
        }

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

for those interested I resolve my issue with:

```
table.on('init', function () {
   table.page('last').draw(false);
});
```

complete code

```
$(document).ready( function () {



        // http://live.datatables.net/ficemafo/1/edit
        $("#table_id").one("preInit.dt", function () {
                $("#table_id_filter label").append('<a data-target="" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'randomization_settings:edit' %}" style="width: 190px;margin-left:10px;">Modify settings</a>');

        });


        if(window.navigator.language.slice(0, 2) == 'fr'){
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5,10],
                "pageLength": 4,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                // "aoColumns" : [
                //     { sWidth: '15%' },
                //     { sWidth: '15%' },
                //     { sWidth: '20%' },
                //     { sWidth: '20%' },
                //     { sWidth: '30%' }
                // ],
                "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                },
            });
            table.on('init', function () {
                table.page('last').draw(false);
            }); 
        } else {
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5,10],
                "pageLength": 4,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                // "aoColumns" : [
                //     { sWidth: '15%' },
                //     { sWidth: '15%' },
                //     { sWidth: '20%' },
                //     { sWidth: '20%' },
                //     { sWidth: '30%' }
                // ],  
            });
            table.on('init', function () {
                table.page('last').draw(false);
            }); 
        }

    } );
```